# PHP - Display number of files of each item

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach, count

My goal is to display the number of folders inside of each listed directories.

[image]

The number of items displayed in the image is from the folder "weeee" only. What should I replace here  $title = 'central/weeee/'; ? or is there something that should be added?

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('parentfolder/' . $_SESSION['name'] . '/file.txt');
$array = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($array as $line) {
    $title = 'central/weeee/';
    $num = count(glob("$title" . "*", GLOB_ONLYDIR)); //count files
    echo "<li><a href='central/$line/home.php' target='_blank' 
                                  style='padding: 10px;
                                         color: black;
                                         font-size: 20px;
                                        
                                         '>$line</a></li>";

    echo $num . "  " . 'item(s)|';
    echo $title; //checking if it's the right directory
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write a recursive function that calculates the number of files in the nested directories.

Comment: what is the output do you want?